# Why do I get "Error Parsing Time" when I use the format string "%FT%T" with Time::Piece->strptime?

Tags: perl, datetime

I am trying to convert `2015-09-11T04:00:00` to a [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) object. I tried:

```
my $date = "2015-09-11T04:00:00";
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%FT%T');
print $t->strftime('%F %T');
```

But I get `Error Parsing Time`. I think it is because I am looking for `%FT%T` and this is causing issues because of the spacing. How would I fix this?

Comment: The documentation seems to imply that should work, but it doesn't work for me either. I had to use `Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')` to get the date to parse. `man strptime` says that `%F` should equal `%Y-%m-%d` and `%T` should equal `%H:%M:%S`... so this is odd.

Comment: I've always gotten this error with the `%F` format specifier. I *think* Time::Piece has platform-specific differences, so it may work on some systems.

Comment: The "just like the man page" documentation is a little optimistic.

Comment: @JimDavis They did [copy](https://metacpan.org/source/RJBS/Time-Piece-1.30/Piece.xs#L315) the strptime implementation from FreeBSD, after all. But unless you're actually running BSD, I think time.h and other things may differ, so you get stuff like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered ditching Time::Piece for something else? [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime), for example, does what it says on the tin:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;

my $date = '2015-09-11T04:00:00';
my $strp = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(pattern => '%FT%T');
my $dt = $strp->parse_datetime($date);

print $dt->datetime;  # prints 2015-09-11T04:00:00
```

Comment: Yes, I ended up doing that. Datetime actually has a module `DateTime::Format::ISO8601`

Comment: Even better! I guess I should have checked before I posted my answer, but I didn't know if you had multiple formats to parse or just the one.

Answer (score 6):

`Time::Piece` seems to have some bugs in this area. In particular, it thinks that `strptime` `%T` is equivalent to `%B %e`, unlike what its documentation claims.

`strftime` `%F` and `%T` don't work for me either, but that may be because I'm on Windows.

Sticking to standard format specifications works fine, though:

```
my $date = "2015-09-11T04:00:00";
my $t = Time::Piece->strptime($date, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S');
print $t->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'), "\n";
```

Comment: I guess it's time to send a pull request.

Comment: It's a mess, `Time::Piece` bundles a old implementation of strptime() from BSD which is hardcoded to use english for non-numerical components, while the strftime() method uses your libc's implementation and is subject for any locale.